# Get certain date between 2 dates in different years

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Declare @FromDate as datetime,
        @ToDate as datetime

set @FromDate = '2000-01-01',
    @ToDate = '2001-01-01'

Select * 
from Mytable 
Where 
    Convert(varchar,ses_begin_date,101) >=  Convert(varchar,@FromDate, 101) 
    AND Convert(varchar,ses_begin_date, 101) <= Convert(varchar,@ToDate,101)
```

This returns no data although there is already data in it .

Comment: Why are you handling dates as varchar?

Comment: And especially bad, using format 101 which produces strings that don't sort in the same way as dates would, and here produces two strings where there's no other possible date value that can appear between them.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need CONVERSION. Just use this

```
    Declare @FromDate as datetime,
        @ToDate as datetime

set @FromDate = '2000-01-01',
    @ToDate = '2001-01-01'

Select * 
from Mytable 
Where 
    ses_begin_date>=  @FromDate 
    AND ses_begin_date<= @ToDate
```

Also if your goal is to get all data for the year 2000, use

```
    Declare @FromDate as datetime,
        @ToDate as datetime

set @FromDate = '2000-01-01',
    @ToDate = '2001-01-01'

Select * 
from Mytable 
Where 
    ses_begin_date>=  @FromDate 
    AND ses_begin_date< @ToDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from Mytable 
Where 
    ses_begin_date>='2000-01-01'
    AND ses_begin_date<= '2001-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use DateDiff function

```
Select *
From Table
Where Datediff(day,@datefrom, ses_begin_date)<=0
and Datediff(day,ses_begin_date,@dateto)<=0
```

Comment: Although this might be correct, I would not advise you to use this as this makes your query un-sarg-able.

Comment: Yes for that purpose use between keyword

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server higher than 2005 ie. 2008 or above than this query 
will result with all the records within the date range.

You were not getting record because you were using "datetime" which also include time part which may not result all the required records. But if you range with only date part than you should either convert it to either "datetime" or to "date" type in both sides while comparing.

This should work.

```
DECLARE 
    @FromDate DATE ,
    @ToDate DATE;

SELECT @FromDate = '2000-01-01',
    @ToDate = '2001-01-01'
```

Either

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    @temp 
WHERE   
    (CONVERT(DATE, ses_begin_date) >=  @FromDate 
    AND CONVERT(DATE, ses_begin_date) <= @ToDate)
```

Or

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM  
    @temp 
WHERE  
    (CONVERT(DATE, ses_begin_date) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate).
```

If you are using version below than 2008 than one way may be to convert it to "int" to remove date part and than make comparison. ie.

```
DECLARE 
    @FromDate int ,
    @ToDate int;

SELECT @FromDate = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2000-01-01',112)),
    @ToDate = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2001-01-01',112))
```

--Either

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    @temp 
WHERE   
    (CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ses_begin_date, 112)) >=  @FromDate 
    AND CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ses_begin_date, 112)) <= @ToDate)
```

--Or

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM  
    @temp 
WHERE  
    (CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ses_begin_date, 112)) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
```